# How are you supposed to get Lockpicking 99?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Found this chest in Temperantia and at first I figured I could open it just because it was a fairly low level area compared to me. Then this happened. Like, seriously?

Or is this chest just not intended to be opened?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As luck would have it, this is actually related to a particular quest: [Hero of the Nopon](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Hero_of_the_Nopon) (from Boreas). No need for 99 lockpicking.

Answer (score -2):

That chest is for Boreas' Blade Quest later in the game. You will have to have him and you will have to fill all four of his food boxes in the Argentum Warehouse first. There is a thieving Nopon that will open it for you. I think it's just not supposed to be opened until that quest.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This was already mentioned in the accepted answer nearly 3 years ago